# Using Google Fi in Northern Cyprus

Tags: turkey, mobile-operators, cyprus, northern-cyprus

I will be visiting Northern Cyprus, via Turkey, in July. I am wondering if my Google Fi phone (android) will work there, especially for data--I will be distance working part of the time. Internet can be pretty patchy, I hear.

For whatever it is worth, it works in Turkey and the Republic of Cyprus. Turkish cell companies seem to have semi-independent cell operators there, so any personal experience someone on this group may have had would be really valuable.

Another data point might be the following: Has anyone used Cyprus (ROC) cell operators in the north? Say not too far from the green line, such as North Nicosia? I may be able to access Google Fi that way, I presume.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out Google Fi does cover northern Cyprus. I will find out how well it works when I travel soon.

**Edit**: Yes, it is working very smoothly.

Comment: Fascinating. How did you find out?

Comment: Called Google itself

Comment: Even more fascinating. You managed to contact a human at _Google_? How on Earth did you manage to do that??

Comment: I imagine that Google Fi is like other phone operators, and has an actual hotline for its users...

Answer (score 2):

I am currently in TRNC, near Iskele on east coast.  I have no cell signal -- phone says emergency calls only.  When we drove around yesterday after crossing the boarder, both my phone and my wife's cell phone had no cell signal.

Chatted with Google Fi support for about an hour (via wifi in condo).  They said they changed something at their end due to my chat.  It started working a few hours later.  Since then, it has mostly worked, but there have been times when I had no signal, but 5 minutes later, 4 bars (in the same place).  WIfe's phone still has no signal.

Comment: I didn't have this issue in two visits, interesting.

Comment: _wonders how he managed to post this answer..._ :)